# What will be the python regex to match this?

Tags: python, regex

Given this string:

```
var python_books = {
   'name': 'Python Notebooks',
   'sub-menu': [{
             'name' : 'Python Research Notebook',
             'snippet' : [
                 'import os, sys, json, time',
                 '',
                 'import numpy as np',
                 'import pandas as pd',
                 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt',
                 'from scipy import stats',
                 '',
                 '%matplotlib inline',
                 'plt.style.use("ggplot")',
                 '%config InlineBackend.figure_format = "retina"',
              ]
         },
         {'name': 'Getting Data', 'sub-menu': []},
         {'name': 'Visualizations', 'sub-menu': []}
         ]
         };
```

I want a regex which can match everything in 'snippet' between [...] these square brackets. I already have tried this regex:
`regex = r"(?:'Python Research Notebook',\s*'snippet' : \[(.|\n)*?\])"`.
But I want to exclude this part from regex: `'Python Research Notebook', 'snippet' :` 
Positive lookbehind is also not working since it contains variable length width due to `\s*`. How do I do this?

Comment: To be clear: you have some Javascript code, and you want to process that code as text, in Python?

Comment: I'd suggest to replace single quotes with double quotes then parse as JSON

Comment: Hint: where the regex says `(?:`, what do you think that means? What would be the meaning of just using `(` instead? This is the difference between **non-capturing** and **capturing** groups, right? Then. The problem is that you want to **capture** only part of the text that the regex matches. Right? Can you see how to use a **capturing group** to get only that part?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel basically I want to replace the snippet part from some javascript code by reading file from disk and writing that file to disk from a python code. I thought reading it as a text and replacing it with string would be the easiest. What do you think?

Comment: @mousetail that would also involve stripping out the `var = `. It seems pretty clear that we're doing some kind of hack job here regardless.

Comment: That's true, but I think it would be a bit more reliable than a regex based solution. It would still fail if a string contains a single or double quote character though.

Comment: @ILS because I don't know how many spaces will be there in between

Comment: @tejal567 is this your expected result ? `['import os, sys, json, time', '', 'import numpy as np', 'import pandas as pd', 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt', 'from scipy import stats', '', '%matplotlib inline', 'plt.style.use("ggplot")', '%config InlineBackend.figure_format = "retina"']`

Comment: @Ramesh yes, its correct

Comment: then why you need regex? i got the output from simple for loop.

Comment: yes you are right @Ramesh. I think simple for loop is better

Comment: @mousetail Lots of replacers ... first replace `"` with `\"`, then replace `\'` with `\\"`, then replace `'` with `"`, and finally replace `\\"` with `'`. Yes there's still a potential of b0rkage, but I think this is good enough for the data.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var_python_books = {
    'name': 'Python Notebooks',
    'sub-menu': [{
        'name': 'Python Research Notebook',
        'snippet': [
            'import os, sys, json, time',
            '',
            'import numpy as np',
            'import pandas as pd',
            'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt',
            'from scipy import stats',
            '',
            '%matplotlib inline',
            'plt.style.use("ggplot")',
            '%config InlineBackend.figure_format = "retina"',
        ]
    },
        {'name': 'Getting Data', 'sub-menu': []},
        {'name': 'Visualizations', 'sub-menu': []}
    ]
};

for i in var_python_books['sub-menu']:
    if i.get('snippet'):
        print(i['snippet'])

>>> ['import os, sys, json, time', '', 'import numpy as np', 'import pandas as pd', 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt', 'from scipy import stats', '', '%matplotlib inline', 'plt.style.use("ggplot")', '%config InlineBackend.figure_format = "retina"']
```